fastboot commands are not executed, although device is being recognized
I am trying to flash a TWRP recovery onto a Blackview BV5500 (MT6580) in Manjaro Linux.
Android Platform Tools and Android udev Rules are installed.
I have no access to the system, so I can't unlock OEM in developer options.
The Problem:
The phone is recognized by fastboot
fastboot devices
E531C1ZM94110604    fastboot
But when I execute commands like
fastboot oem info
fastboot oem unlock
fastboot flashing unlock
there is no response at all; no error message. It is not going back to command prompt, so it looks like it's doing something or waiting, but nothing happens (I waited for a long time).
I spent many hours searching for a solution, but nothing worked. What I tried so far:

Changing cables
Changing USB ports (USB2 and USB3)
sudo fastboot and sudo $(which fastboot)
additional udev rule for manager to ignore handling the device in
/etc/udev/rules.d/20-mm-blacklist-mtk.rules
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0e8d", ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1"
additional udev rule to make an permanent entry in
/etc/udev/rules.d/80-persistent-usb.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="0e8d", ATTR{idProduct}=="*"
SP Flash Tool throws an error COM_PORT_OPEN_FAIL(1013)

Strange thing I noticed, when in fastboot mode lsusb returns
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0bb4:0c01 HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.) Dream / ADP1 / G1 / Magic / Tattoo / FP1
but when it's booted into system lsusb returns
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 0e8d:2008 MediaTek Inc. Cyrus Technology CS 24
Like it is recognized as two different phones...
I am out of ideas. Any help is welcome!
Thanks a lot!
-tom

if you can't unlock OEM in developer options you can't unlock bootloader from fastboot. use mtkclient instead. is there any response if you try to flash something? if not try recent fastboot binary, it should throw a error. the last part of your question is normal, each mode has it's own vid pid

If I need to unlock OEM in developer options first, does it not defeat the purpose of fastboot oem unlock?
I am using the lastest fastboot version 35.0.1-android-tools.
Trying to flash recovery leeds to the same result, a empty line, no error message and freeze until I cancel.
I will try mtkclient and report back.

@alecxs I installed mtkclient following the ArchLinux instructions here: https://github.com/bkerler/mtkclient . I have all the modules (including mock) in ~/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ but running ~/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mtkclient/mtk_gui.py tells me it's missing the mock module. Looks like a directory issue, but I am somehow lost. Can you help?

you don't need the gui just run command from cmd line

@alecxs When I try to run python mtk.py from cmd line it tells me it's missing the colorama module, altough it is installed along with all the other modules here ~/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/. Pip3 tells me requirements are already satisfied. I reinstalled everything, made sure to install with python3 and pip3. I don't know how to solve this...

I don't know about Manjaro or ArchLinux but no issues with Ubuntu here. maybe try re_livedvdV4.iso

@alecxs Ok, I will ask in the Manjaro Forum. Thanks for your help!

maybe try older release instead of main https://github.com/bkerler/mtkclient/tree/2.0.1.freeze
